# How do I create a vertical Histogram in python with stars without using matplotlib?

Tags: python

Part 2 - Vertical Histogram (extension)
Extend your program to add a vertical histogram (stars in a category should go downwards),

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP4mL.png

I have currently produced a code that allows students and staff to predict progression outcomes at the end of each academic year.The program prompts for the number of credits at pass, defer and fail i.e (120 at pass, 0 at defer and 0 at fail) and then displays the appropriate progression outcome for an individual student (i.e., progress, trailing, module retriever or exclude).

I have asked the user a question at the end "enter y to continue or q to quit". Upon entering "q" a vertical histogram should form with the data that has been input by the staff member during a program run and work for any number of outcomes.

Comment: Can you give more context about what you want it to look like, e.g. an example output, so we have a better idea of what you're asking for?

Comment: Why not Matplotlib? Unfortunately, I think it's the only library available for plotting in Python (it's not great, I get it). Seaborn is based on Matplotlib but makes the process a bit easier and prettier.

Comment: @AndrewWei Hi, i have added an image of what the outcome should look like.